# Delphi XE, worker thread delay with indy tcpclient cause Exception

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy

I was making a program using delphi implementing worker thread tecnic from this  [link](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/25707)

what i want to implement is when the delay procedeure is called, i need to send a TCP signal to a server.

when I compiled this code in XE2 and XE7 it worked, but the memory keep growing gradually and slowly. and program will hang a week later.

but when i try compiled it in xe8, it worked but soemtimes it raised

2:21:34: EAccessViolation error raised, with message : Access violation at address 0063CA40 in module 'form1.exe'. Read of address 00000000

If i remove the idTCPclient it will work just fine. from the delay procedure.

here is my partial code.

```
procedure TWorkerThread.Execute; 
begin 
  //doing alot of stuff here      

  delay2(Stop2, result, rond, Datetxt);

  //doing alot of stuff here also

  FreeOnTerminate := true; 

end; 


procedure TWorkerThread.delay2(i: TDateTime; h: string; r: string; d:     string);
var
  TimeUp: Boolean;
  T, comp: integer;
  a: string;
 OnTCP: TIdTCPClient;

begin
  TimeUp := False;
try
OnTCP := TIdTCPClient.Create(Nil);
try
  OnTCP.Host := '127.0.0.1';
  OnTCP.Port := 5000;
  OnTCP.Connect;

  While TimeUp = False do
  begin

    try
      comp := CompareDateTime(now, i);
    except
      on E: Exception do
        logging(E.ClassName + ' error raised, with message : ' + E.Message);
    end;

    if (comp = 1) then
    begin
      TimeUp := True;
    end
    else

    begin
      TimeUp := False;
      try
        T := SecondsBetween(now, i);
      except
        on E: Exception do
          logging(E.ClassName + ' error raised, with message : ' +
            E.Message);
      end;

      a :=  IntToStr(T);
      OnTCP.IOHandler.Write('OK' + h+d+r+a +   sLineBreak);

      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin // 1
          Form1.Label8.Caption := IntToStr(T);
        end); // 1
      sleep(700);

    end;

  end;
  OnTCP.Disconnect;
finally
  OnTCP.Free;
end;
 except
   on E: Exception do
     logging(E.ClassName + ' error raised, with message : ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try to understand and follow what's written here and in its replies:

http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.internet.winsock/201011/1011125063.html

Comment: I see nothing in this code that allocates any memory that could be getting leaked, unless it is being allocated inside of `logging()` and never freed. The only things that could be causing a reading AV at address 0 (meaning a nil pointer is being read from) are your `TThread.Synchronize()` procedure if either `Form1` or `Label8` are not available, and `logging()` if it is not thread-safe. So that is two possible errors pointing at `logging()` as the culprit.  What does `logging()` actually do internally? Have you tried running the code inside the debugger and see what is actually crashing?

Comment: Thanks @Remy lebau, you always come to help. my indy version is 1.0.6.2.5263  the logging procedure just like this:     procedure TWorkerThread.logging(a: string);
begin
  Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin // 1
      Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(Time) + ': ' + a);
    end); // 1
end; Honestly i'm a noob, i never run it in a debugger but tonight i will find out. thanks for pointing me the direction.

Comment: The biggest skill that beginners seem to lack is debugging and problem solving. What you need to concentrate on is acquiring those skills. Make that you next goal.

Comment: there are series of this exception: First chance exception at $771AC42D. Exception class EInvalidPointer with message 'Invalid pointer operation'. Process Form1.exe (23328) inside above procedure. I dunno what causing it. :( did i free something that does not belong to? ...